# How to Parsing Multiple JSON format in One Models to Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I am trying to parse 2 different JSON formats in dart, in my case when data is not empty it will get a format like this

```json
"data": {
        "type": "iksknew",
        "id": "a8b27eb5-71cd-4cdf-928c-f200f9c0a2ef",
        "attributes": {
            "namaPeserta": "Darwadi",
            "namapelatihan": Train",
            "rtl": "Learn Code",
            "penerapan": true,
            "fileEvidence": "http://localhost:8008/api/v1/iksk/file-evidence/a8b27eb5-71cd-4cdf-928c-f200f9c0a2ef",
            "dateCreated": "2021-07-15T23:02:55.000000Z",
            "dateUpdated": "2021-07-15T23:02:55.000000Z"
        }
```

if the data is empty it will get a form like this

```json
data : []
```

how do I do that when the data is empty I can use it to define the condition? here are the models and methods that I made

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// actual model used
class UserModel {
  Data? data;
  Meta? meta;

  UserModel({this.data, this.meta});

  // factory method

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) =>
      UserModel(
          data: Data.fromJson(jsonData['data']),
          meta: Meta.fromJson(jsonData['meta']));

  // api connector
  static Future<UserModel> getLoginData({required nik, required apiUrl}) async {
    var body = {
      "type": "auth",
      "attributes": {"nik": nik}
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(apiUrl);
    final res = await http.post(url,
        body: json.encode(body), headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
    return UserModel.fromJson(jsonObject);
  }
}

// casting API
class Data {
  String? id;
  Attributes? attributes;
  Links? links;

  Data({this.id, this.attributes, this.links});

  // factory method to parsing attributes
  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
        attributes: Attributes.fromJson(json['attributes']), id: json['id']);
  }
}

class Attributes {
  // define result in api
  String? nik;
  String? namaPeserta;
  String? kodePelatihan;
  String? namaPelatihan;
  String? token;
  int? expiresIn;
  String? tokenType;

  Attributes({
    this.nik,
    this.namaPeserta,
    this.kodePelatihan,
    this.namaPelatihan,
    this.token,
  });

  // factory method to parsing json
  factory Attributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> attributeObject) {
    return Attributes(
      nik: attributeObject['nik'],
      namaPeserta: attributeObject['namaPeserta'],
      kodePelatihan: attributeObject['kodePelatihan'],
      token: attributeObject['token'],
    );
  }
}

// links class
class Links {
  String? self;

  // constructor
  Links({this.self});

  // factory method
  factory Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Links(
      self: json['self'],
    );
  }

}

// meta class to parse messages
class Meta {
  String? api;

  Meta({this.api});

  // factory method to parsing meta value
  factory Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> metaJson) {
    return Meta(api: metaJson['api']);
  }
}
```

if I run and get Empty Data I got errors like this

```sh
List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>
```

I try to Handle with `FutureBuilder` Like this but I still fail if I success to get data but have another error

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
            isDataEmpty = false;
    print('i got data')
 } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
   print('Must be Empty Data')
} else {
    return CircularProcessIndicator
}
```

how To Handle it? and return to Empty condition if response data is Empty?

Comment: There seem to be two response types for data. A Map when you have data, and a List when it's empty. Could you check if that's correct? It seems a little weird.

Comment: yes, it's the correct data response I check with postman and got that result